# Entity Framework: subset entity of larger entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity, subset

Sooo basically I have a table called Comment. On that table I have three fields,

- ID
- Title
- Text

I've created an Entity object for the table already and it maps all three fields, but what I want now is another Entity called CommentHeader that will map only ID and Title. I want to only load the titles of all the comments and not the text for speed reasons. So what's the best way for going about this?

I'm not looking for a Select statement with a var object. I can figure that one out on my own and I really don't like that solution because I'd much rather abstract it behind an Entity object.

I've tried the obvious solution, which was to just copy the original Entity object and delete Text from it. That resulted in an error because only one Entity can map to one table without conditions. It sounds to me like I have no choice but to use a Select statement. I just wanted to make sure before I did something stupid.

(By the way this example only has three fields for simplicity's sake. Assume that the header could have considerably more fields in it. This is the primary reason I don't want to just use a select with a var object, because it's not just one field but could be a whole bunch of fields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way probably would be to create a view ("CommentHeaders") in the database that only selects ID and title from the Comment table. Then update your model and add the view, which will create a new entity based on those columns.

Comment: As an update to this. The other solution I've found would be to lazy load the scalar attribute. Unfortunately EF does not support lazy loading attributes yet, so this is the trick currently done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786783/can-i-lazy-load-scalar-properties-with-the-ado-net-entity-framework. This method is best if the second class you are creating is very similar to the first. In such a case I would not create a second class at all.