# Load File using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework-4

Right now I have file upload/download through Entity Framework working but I see an issue coming up. In the scenario when i want to get a list of all the files associated with a record, I don't want it to pull the `Data` property, just the `FileId` and `Name`, because the files can be up to `10MB` each.

I have `LazyLoading` disabled so I'm thinking about putting the `Data` column into another table and only load the data when I want. That way I can just supply a link to a `controller` with the `FileId` I want to download.  But maybe there is a better way? All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

My `File` entity has the following properties:

```
FileId
FkRecord
Name
Data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need to put data column in another table - just create another entity in the designer and move you [Data] column in it. don't forget to create corresponding table mapping in designer - map you data column to the column in db table.

Also create 1 to 1 association between entities. And you could use navigational properties and do not need to alter you db table!

I found similar discussion: 
[Can I lazy load scalar properties with the ADO.Net Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786783/can-i-lazy-load-scalar-properties-with-the-ado-net-entity-framework)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed, I guess I just wasn't typing in the correct magic search phrases into SO.